# Are there incompatibility issues between Oracle Forms 11g and Oracle Forms 12?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

I need the Oracle Forms 11g installer, but on the website I only find the version of Oracle Forms 12.  Will I have incompatibility problems if I install Oracle Forms 12? If so, which ones?

Answer (score 0):

If any Oracle software product is desupported, you can't download it from OTN. Though, if you have valid Support contract, Oracle will provide it for you. Otherwise, you're out of luck.

As of 12c vs. 11g Forms versions: generally speaking, higher version is capable of opening, compiling and running lower form versions. There certainly are some differences; which ones and what they mean, see in any version's "New features" documentation.

As I don't use versions you mentioned, I can't tell from my own experience.